# Setting CSS margin-top so that the content does not appear on screen in any device before scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Maybe this is a noob question but I cant find any proper solution for this.

I have a single page website and there is two div. Lets say div1 and div2. I want to show the first div1 while page load but div2 will be under div1. User only see on scroll but it can not be appear on viewport.

I can manage it giving margin-top but it is not responsive. On my device its ok but on other device div2 appears on viewport under the div1.

How to fix that?

Comment: What's wrong with `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;` ?

Comment: This has to be done with margin-top. Maybe I could not clear the problem :(

div2 will be visible under the div1

Comment: You can use `display:none` on div 2 and use `display:block` on `$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   
});`

Comment: You have to provide in question itself minimalistic sample replicating your issue. I don't see for the moment any reason why you have to use margin for that... BTW, read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please post your html and css code so that others may offer help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the `viewport height` units. Give `height: 100vh;` to div1 and it will have the height of the viewport browser, so the div2 will be always out of the viewport. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) you have more info about css units. And [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) the  browser support.